# Using props within a media query in styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have this code that I want to use the props after a media query, see below code.

```
    export const Box = styled.div<IBox>`
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;

      ${({ column }) => FlexBasis(column)};
      ${({ display = "flex" }) => Display[display]};
      margin: ${({ margin }) => margin};
      padding: ${({ padding }) => padding};

      /**
      * This part below is the problem
      * margin gives error as type any
      /*
      ${media.mobile`
      margin: ${({ margin }) => margin};
      `};
      }
```

My question is how do I use props inside the media query.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just discovered that this works only problem is just having to repeat it all the time

```
/**
* This part below is the problem
* margin gives error as type any
/*
```

...other codes

```
${media.mobile`
margin: ${({ margin }: IBox) => margin};
`};
```